# Какой вариант триггера оптимальнее для выборки товаров с пагинацией и по категориям

Tags: mysql, триггер, insert

Подскажите, какой вариант триггера оптимальнее или как протестировать это дело в phpMyAdmin?
Предыстория - БД InnoDB, в таблице products 2'000'000 строк, для отображения с сортировкой и пагинацией по 24 товара из текущей категории запускается следующий алгоритм:
1. первый запрос подсчитывает кол-во товаров в текущей категории, стандартным COUNT(*) с добавлением WHERE "текущая категория" по всей таблице products, запрос нужен для формирования ссылок пагинации
2. второй запрос получает набор ID товаров, согласно условиям сортировки
3. третий запрос получает полные данные по этим 24 товарам через IN

1-й запрос самый тяжелый, хоть и самый простой - 400мс - поэтому решил получать кол-во товаров для текущей категории не запросом в огромную таблицу с 2'000'000 товаров,а в новую таблицу, где для каждой категории будет хранится одна строка с числом, а записывать-обновлять в эту таблицу триггером.
Вот и вопрос - обновлять число товаров оптимальнее через counts=counts+1 или же запускать подсчет при каждом добавлении нового товара через пробежку по всей таблице товаров через `COUNT(*)` ? Вроде бы первый вариант более скоростной, но что, если добавлять товары будет несколько пользователей, например, этих пользователей около 10'000 ? БД будет формировать очередь или наступит хаос? А что если импортировать сразу пачку товаров, например, 20'000 товаров за раз, как тут будет вести себя БД?
Фух,ну и простыня,сорри)))

Вот этот запрос-тормоз
[image: запрос-тормоз]

**UPD.** Как подсказали два уважаемых человека, спасибо им, нужен индекс на участвующие в запросе поля.
Запрос: `EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM`products`WHERE active=1 and category_id=1`
Для одного индекса и для пяти индексов результат одинаков, в итоге время снизилось с 400 до 200мс.
[image: explain]

Тоже не густо... Что еще предпринять-то?

Comment: Какой нахрен триггер? нет бы индекс создать...

Comment: индексы созданы, под два вида сортировки //ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX `acn` (`active`,`category_id`,`name`), 
//ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX `acp` (`active`,`category_id`,`price`)

Comment: Для проблемного запроса оба индекса - ниачём...

Comment: Что бы индекс мог быть использован в where должны быть условия на все поля, с которых он начинается. Т.е. пока в запросе нет условия на поле active (лучше на равенство) указанные индексы использованы быть не могут. Нужен как минимум один индекс в котором поле category_id будет первым

Answer (score 0):

На хабре есть статья, где описывается как оптимизировать запрос COUNT(*) https://habr.com/ru/post/490320/